# Is there a JDFTVAL equivalent for SQL?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

For Iseries/IBMi DB2.

I am joining multiple files/tables together.

I have written the code in both DDS and SQL.

The DDS Logical File is working exactly as expected, but I can not use it for embedded sql in rpgle as it then defaults to the SQE engine resulting in horrendous performance.

The SQL view, on the other hand had `NULLs` until I used `IFNULL( MBRDESCR, '')`. But now `MBRDECSR` is a `VARCHAR`. Which is unacceptable.

So how do I create a SQL join without `NULLs` and `VARCHARs`?

Requested Sample Code:

**DDS:**

```
                                            JDFTVAL                                              
                R TRANSR                    JFILE(TRANSPF MBRPF)                                

                J                           JOIN(1 2)
                                            JFLD(MBRID MBRID)                                  
      *                                                
                  TRANSID                   JREF(1)     
                  MBRID                     JREF(1)                               
                  MBRNAME                   JREF(2)                               
                  MBRSURNME                 JREF(2)                               
      *                   
                K TRANSID                                                       
                K MBRID
```

SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW TRANSV01 AS (                 
    SELECT TRANSID                                 ,
           MBRID                                   ,                 
           CAST(IFNULL(MBRNAME  , '') as Char(20)) ,                 
           CAST(IFNULL(MBRSURNME, '') as Char(25))                  
    FROM TRANSPF
    --Member Name                                                               
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MBRPF on MBRID = MBRID     
) RCDFMT TRANSR;
```

Please note the following:

1. Example above is simplified
2. Not every MBRID in the TRANSPF has a corresponding entry in the MBRPF (ie. no referential constraint). Thus when MBRPF is joined to the TRANSPF, there will be NULL values in MBRNAME, MBRSURNME. Unless JDFTVAL or IFNULL() is used.
3. I prefer not to have a VARCHAR, because of performance and extname() in rpgle.
4. I prefer not to have NULL values, I do not want the pgm to have to handle them.

Comment: I don't understand the entire question.  For me, at least a little snippet of what you've done in the DDS would help.  I can help you solve the "unacceptable" varchar issue (though I am bewildered why that would be an issue).   Simply use CAST(IFNULL(MBRDESCR,'') AS CHAR(50)).

Comment: I agree with Dennis.  And please show your existing SQL code as well.

Comment: So if I read correctly (other than the oversiplified "JOIN MBRPF ON MBRID=MBRID" which should give you an error even if it doesn't) the CAST solves the problem, right?  Or do issues remain?  (I was going to comment about the "performance and extname()" comment, but decided to let it go.  You're welcome.  :) )

Comment: @Dennis, its correct the CAST does solve the issue. Also the JOIN (M = M) will cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's the 'Allows the null value' that you find undesirable, use a UNION.  The first SELECT chooses all the rows that match, which will set the NOT NULL property for you.  The second SELECT chooses all the rows that don't have a match - you provide filler fields for those.

```
CREATE VIEW TRANSV01 AS (                 
    SELECT TRANSID                                 ,
           MBRID                                   ,                 
           MBRNAME  ,
           MBRSURNME
    FROM TRANSPF
    --Member Name                                                               
    JOIN MBRPF on MBRID = MBRID     
  UNION
    SELECT TRANSID                                 ,
           MBRID                                   ,                 
           CAST('') as Char(20)) ,                 
           CAST('') as Char(25))                  
    FROM TRANSPF
    --Member Name                                                               
    EXCEPTION JOIN MBRPF on MBRID = MBRID     
) RCDFMT TRANSR;
```

Comment: That is, unless MBRNAME and/or MBRSURNME have null values. Then this will not have the desired effect.

Comment: True!  However, if the OP was using ALWNULL in the DDS he probably wouldn't be worried about SQL's 'Allows the null value'.  If there really were null values, he'd need additional UNIONs to individually handle them.  Ugly?  Sure is.  A good reason to embrace that there are nulls in a relational database and start handling them in the code base rather than going through ugly efforts to make them go away.

Comment: @BuckCalabro, Thank you. Handling in Code it is.

Comment: @BuckCalabro this is expecially so when working with multiple vendors. For example, in Oracle, there is no difference between '' (with no spaces between) and NULL. Put another way, to that DB engine, an empty string IS a NULL. There's no end to the frustration that causes me. And they seem to think that's the way it should be; it's not a bug. For example: <<WHERE SOMECOLUMN = '' OR SOMECOLUMN <> ''>> is guaranteed to never match, since nothing is ever equal to, greater than, nor less than NULL.  Not even NULL.